# Getting value from dropdown in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am trying to make a "clock in / out site" and one of the functions is for the user to edit old clock ins/outs. i have added a dropdown with 2 values "IND" and "UD". How do i get these values out, and send them to my "CHECKIN" sql value.
 I hope you know what iam trying to explain.

this is what it looks like:

[image]

The Dropdown:

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
         <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Ind</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="UD">Ud</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

what ive tried:

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
   string val = row.Cells[3].ToString();
   SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("CHECKEDIN", val);
}
```

and aswell as:

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GridView1.FindControl("DropDownList2");
    string val = ddl.SelectedValue;
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("CHECKEDIN", val);
}
```

Both of these return "null" tho

Comment: Wihout trying it I would certainly think the second example, casting as DropDownList, would work. Is it possible that you are rebinding on page load and wiping out the selected value (check if page postback?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`RowDataBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)** event of `GridView`.

**Code**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow 
               && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList2");
        string val = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("CHECKEDIN", val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the sender back to a DropDownlist and get the selected value

```
DropDownList dropDownList = sender as DropDownList;
string val = dropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

But how will you know with this method which row the DropDownList belongs to?

You can use a trick for that, like abusing the CSS class to get the correct row number.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>
```

And get the row number in code behind.

```
int rowNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dropDownList.CssClass);
```

Comment: i see what youre getting at, but how do i implement this? all in the "onselectedindexchanged" ??